# Why object returned as "reference of value of pointer set to nullptr" is a valid object (singleton) (C++)?

Tags: c++, singleton

I recently saw example incomplete singleton class code in a C++ tutorial and I can't explain myself why it works.

```
#include <iostream>

class Singleton
{
    private:
        static Singleton* s_Instance;
    public:
        static Singleton& Get()
        {
            // I put this check to see if it really is nullptr
            if (s_Instance == nullptr)
                std::cout << "nullptr" << std::endl;

            return *s_Instance;
        }

        void Hello()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
};

Singleton* Singleton::s_Instance = nullptr;

int main()
{
    Singleton::Get().Hello();
}
```

Now this is obviously not a real singleton but that's not the point.

I can't understand why returning the value of a pointer which is set to `nullptr` returns an instance of the class and why it's possible to get the value of `nullptr`. Or is something else happening that I'm missing?

Comment: It's called "undefined behaviour". A C++ program that appears to work isn't necessarily a valid C++ program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undefined behavior as @molbdnilo pointed out. Let's check these articles.

- [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest) | The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=633)
- [The Hacks of Life: The Dangers of Super Smart Compilers](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2015/12/the-dangers-of-super-smart-compilers.html)